# How to to save one document based on an if statement in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, docx

I am trying to save a document based on a if statement.

**Here I am creating radiobuttons:**

```
info = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]


vars = []
for idx,i in enumerate(info):
    var = IntVar(value=0)
    vars.append(var)
    lblOption = Label(main,text=i)
    btnYes = Radiobutton(main, text="Yes", variable=var, value=2)
    btnNo = Radiobutton(main, text="No", variable=var, value=1)
    btnNa = Radiobutton(main, text="N/A", variable=var,value=0)
    lblOption.grid(column=4,row=idx, sticky = W)
    btnYes.grid(column=1,row=idx)
    btnNo.grid(column=2,row=idx)
    btnNa.grid(column=3,row=idx)
```

**Here I am creating a document**

```
document = Document()

#add table
table = document.add_table(1, 4)
#style table
table.style = 'Table Grid'

#populate header row
heading_cells = table.rows[0].cells
heading_cells[0].text = "Options"
heading_cells[1].text = "Yes"
heading_cells[2].text = "No"
heading_cells[3].text = "N/a"

for idx, item in enumerate(vars):
    cells = table.add_row().cells
    cells[0].text = info[idx]  # gets the option name
    val = item.get()  #radiobutton value
    if val == 2:  # checks if yes
        cells[1].text = "*"
    elif val == 1:   # checks if no
        cells[2].text = "*"
    elif val == 0:   # checks if N/A
        cells[3].text = "*"

#save doc
document.save("test.docx")
```

**Work behind the scenes:**

- Out of the 3 radio-button Yes, No, N/a.. Only one can be chosen.
- Next, when pressed a button `save`.. it creates a table in `docx`, Options is in `row 0` appending down along with selected values of Yes, no & N/a.

As an example:

```
Options       Yes      No     N/a
Option 1       *
Option 2               *
Option 3       *
```

**My Problem:**

I can simply press `save` and it saves the file as `test.docx`.

Now, I am trying to figure out how to save the file as `Failed.docx`

The `Failed.docx` will only be created if one or more out of all the options has a `no` value selected.

As an example below, this would be saved as `Test.docx`, because not a single Option has a `no` value selected:

```
Options       Yes      No     N/a
Option 1       *
Option 2                       *
Option 3       *
```

An example below, this would be saved as `Failed.docx`, because `no` option has been selected for one of the options on the left.

As an example:

```
Options       Yes      No     N/a
Option 1       *
Option 2               *
Option 3       *
```

**Here is what I have tried so far:**

```
for x in cells[2].text:
    if "*" in x:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")
```

This detects `*` within the `cell[2]` (This is row 2 linked to `No` value).

And if a 'no' value has been selected it prints out true but also prints out false

As an example:

```
Options       Yes      No     N/a
Option 1       *
Option 2               *
Option 3       *
```

Output of the `for loop` :

```
False
True
False
```

But if it detects `False` and `True` both files will be saved. I am totally confused where to go from here..

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**: The `'Failed.docx'` will only be created `if one or more` out of all the `options` has a **`no`** value selected.

This can be rephrased to:

```
     if any option has NO
```

You have build a `list` of `Boolean` from the condition `value == NO`,
like `[False, True, False]`

---

- [Built-in - any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)

  > **any(iterable)**
  >
  > Return True if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, return False.

---

```
    YES = 2; NO = 1; NA = 0

    print(vars)

    if any([v.get() == NO for v in vars]):
        print('Failed.docx')

    else:
        print('test.docx')
```

> **Output**:

```
[2, 0, 2]
test.docx

[2, 1, 2]
Failed.docx
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201048/discussion-between-stovfl-and-sharks-tale).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
for x in cells[2].text:
    if "*" in x:
        print("Failed.docx")
    elif "*" not in x:
        print("Test.docx")
```

this checks if any `"*"` is inside your `no` row, if it exists save as `Failed.docx` if not save as `Test.docx`

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. If I select a `no` option it returns me `Failed.docx`. But if none of the `no` is selected, it does nothing?  does not run the elif value..

Comment: Try this: `else:` and remove `"*" not in x`