# How to save docx file based on values chosen from tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, docx

**Here is my code:**

```
from tkinter import *
from docx import Document

root = Tk()



info = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]


vars = []
for idx,i in enumerate(info):
    var = IntVar(value=0)
    vars.append(var)
    lblOption = Label(root,text=i)
    btnYes = Radiobutton(root, text="Yes", variable=var, value=2)
    btnNo = Radiobutton(root, text="No", variable=var, value=1)
    btnNa = Radiobutton(root, text="N/A", variable=var,value=0)
    lblOption.grid(column=4,row=idx, sticky = W)
    btnYes.grid(column=1,row=idx)
    btnNo.grid(column=2,row=idx)
    btnNa.grid(column=3,row=idx)


def save():
    document = Document()

    #add table
    table = document.add_table(1, 4)
    #style table
    table.style = 'Table Grid'

    #populate header row
    heading_cells = table.rows[0].cells
    heading_cells[0].text = "Options"
    heading_cells[1].text = "Yes"
    heading_cells[2].text = "No"
    heading_cells[3].text = "N/a"

    for idx, item in enumerate(vars):
        cells = table.add_row().cells
        cells[0].text = info[idx]  # gets the option name
        val = item.get()  #radiobutton value
        if val == 2:  # checks if yes
            cells[1].text = "*"
        elif val == 1:   # checks if no
            cells[2].text = "*"
        elif val == 0:   # checks if N/A
            cells[3].text = "*"

        for x in cells[2].text:
            if "*" in x:
                print("Failed.docx")
            elif "*" not in x:
                print("Test.docx")

savebtn = Button(root, text = "Save", command = save).grid()

root.mainloop()
```

This is my previous question: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58439001/how-to-to-save-one-document-based-on-an-if-statement-in-python)

I have used one of the answers to combine it with my question.

**What I am trying to achieve:**

If `no` has been selected for any of the options via the radio buttons, then save the document as `failed.docx` if every option has been selected without any `no's` then save the file as `Test.docx`.

**My problem is:**

Why is my last for loop and if statement is not working.

When I select a no option it returns me Failed.docx. But if none of the `no'` is selected, it does nothing? does not run the elif statement at all.

Comment: Have you tried to print and see what `x` contains for selections?

Comment: @Lafexlos it prints `*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are writing to docx row by row by creating `cells` on each iteration. 
cells is a row that contains three radiobutton values for a single option. Let's say if you choose `Yes` for option3, cells would contain [* '' ''] for its iteration.

`cells[0] = *`
`cells[1] = ''`
`cells[2] = ''`

Also when you try to iterate over `cells[1].text`, you are trying to iterate on an empty item. That's why it never gets into `if-elif` statements because it never gets into for loop.
(not sure if I managed to explain this clearly but if you use a value for non-selected radiobuttons or debugger, you can see quite clearly what's going on)

For a solution, since you want to check all values for a single column, you can use [table.column](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/table.html#docx.table.Table.columns).

```
for idx, item in enumerate(vars):
    cells = table.add_row().cells
    cells[0].text = info[idx]  # gets the option name
    val = item.get()  #radiobutton value
    if val == 2:  # checks if yes
        cells[1].text = "*"
        cells[2].text = "not-selected"
        cells[3].text = "not-selected"
    elif val == 1:   # checks if no
        cells[2].text = "*"
        cells[1].text = "not-selected"
        cells[3].text = "not-selected"
    elif val == 0:   # checks if N/A
        cells[3].text = "*"
        cells[1].text = "not-selected"
        cells[2].text = "not-selected"

fn = 'Test.docx'
for cell in table.columns[2].cells[1:4]: #column2 is No column, 1:4 excludes header cell
    if cell.text == '*':
        fn = 'Failed.docx'
        break

print(fn)
```

Comment: also, what does `table.columns[2].cells[1:4]` do?

Comment: @sharksTale `table.columns` gets the all column objects in created `table`. `column[2]` is the `No` column of the table. (0=option names, 1=Yes, 2=No, 3=N/A) Command `table.columns[2].cells`, gets all the cells in `No` column. First cell (cells[0]) is the header so you want to check `cells[1:4]`.

Comment: can `[1:4]` be changed to `[1:]` or would that be a problem?

Comment: @sharksTale Yes, since the table you created has 4 columns, `[1:]` and `[1:4]` are the same for this case.

Comment: Hi, im still having issues with this code in terms of saving the documets, based on the options chosen from radiobuttons

Comment: If I replace `fn =` to `fn = document.save("Test.docx)"` and the failed version also, they both generate when clicked saved

Comment: @sharksTale I used `fn` as `filename`. After the `for` loop, instead of `print` you should use `document.save(fn)`